# Java HttpClient returns "501 Method Not Implemented" and "POST to / not supported"

Tags: java, httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` to submit a form to a webpage and when I look at HTTP header which browser is sending it is definitely sending POST request there.

But when I try to do the same with `HttpClient` it returnes error page with the message in the subject.

```
HttpPost httpost = (HttpPost) prepareRequest(new HttpPost(targetURL));
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

Comment: It might depend on how the website you're trying to post to is configured. They may be checking user-agent headers and disallowing unknown ones.

Comment: httpost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

solved the problem

Comment: This is because HttpClient includes charset used to encode the entity in the Content-Type header: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', which some server side scripts are unable to handle correctly

Answer (score 0):

501 could also mean that your Content type is not set correctly for some web-servers.

If you don't want to deal with this low-level API, this would be the code needed in Resty for a x-www-form-urlencoded POST.

```
Resty r = new Resty();
String result = r.text(targetUrl, form(nvps)).toString();
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [Resty](http://beders.github.com/Resty/Resty/Overview.html).